# Amsterdam connection

Tags: airports, amsterdam

I'm flying from Dubrovnik, Croatia on EasyJet to Amsterdam, and connecting on Delta to Boston. How much time is needed for this connection?

Comment: Are you flying with checked bags (3hrs) or with only carry-on (90 min might work)?

Comment: @GeorgeY. Those times might work if there could magically be a guarantee that the EasyJet flight would be on time.  Since that's not possible, the traveler has to weigh the probability of missing the second flight against the cost of missing the second flight and the cost of leaving extra time between the flights as a buffer.  If the traveler is on a tight budget, for example, it might be best to plan an extra day in Amsterdam, so if the first flight is cancelled altogether it will be possible to make other arrangements to get to the second one.